# Как изменить пример ответа в Swagger UI?

Tags: c#, swagger, swaggerui

Как изменить пример ответа для поля типа Decimal с 0 на 0,00 в Swagger UI? Пробовал вот это [решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73958642/how-to-change-response-example-value-in-swagger-ui/73958768#73958768), но не получилось. Также отображает 0.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70508661/6808809

Answer (score 1):

Сформировал ответ на основании помощи @EvgeniyZ (накидываем ему респектов выше):

```
public class DecimalSchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
    {
        if (context.Type == typeof(decimal))
            schema.Example = new OpenApiDouble(0.01d);
    }
}
```

И в настройке свагера добавляем:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SchemaFilter<DecimalSchemaFilter>();
});
```